# jQuery datepicker highlight range loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to highlight date ranges on a jQuery datepicker.

```
  var dates = new Array();
  dates[0] = [new Date(2014,2,23), new Date(2014,2,30)];
  dates[1] = [new Date(2014,2,13), new Date(2014,2,20)];

  $(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: '-0m',
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            for (i=0;i<dates.length;i++) {
                var date1 = dates[i][0];
                var date2 = dates[i][1];
                return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
            }
        }
    })
  });
```

The above doesn't work since only one range is visible. How can I get a loop going so that it highlights more than one range? Thanks for your help!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7YWL/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the return inside the loop
for that reason on the end of the first loop the function is returning true or false

You should do something like:

```
var dates = new Array();
  dates[0] = [new Date(2014,2,23), new Date(2014,2,30)];
  dates[1] = [new Date(2014,2,13), new Date(2014,2,20)];

  $(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: '-0m',
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var bool = true;
            for (i=0;i<dates.length;i++) {
                var date1 = dates[i][0];
                var date2 = dates[i][1];
                bool = bool && date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : "";
            }
            return bool;
        }
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var dates = new Array();
dates[0] = [new Date(2014, 2, 23), new Date(2014, 2, 30)];
dates[1] = [new Date(2014, 2, 13), new Date(2014, 2, 20)];

$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: '-0m',
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var flag = false,
                date1, date2, i;
            for (i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
                date1 = dates[i][0];
                date2 = dates[i][1];

                flag = (!date1 || date.getTime() >= date1.getTime()) && (!date2 || date.getTime() <= date2.getTime())
                if (flag) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return [true, flag ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
        }
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uqy9V/)